# Why the pattern to power down

Tags: factory-reset

attempting to power off my samsung t560nu to prepair for a hard reset upon pressing the power button the tablet requests the security pattern why is it doing this the pattern is the reason im trying to factory reset

Comment: This all comes after I put a security pattern on the Tab E gave it to my mother for christmas.she put it in a drawer and 8 months later demands that I produce the pattern

Comment: Instead of making comments on your question, you should edit the original question to make it clear. Comments are meant to clarify the question and additional information or details should be added to the original question. This is a Q&A group, so your question should be clearly defined with all relevant information contained within the question. It should not be for potential answer givers to guess or assume your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't have a question here, but since you seem new I will not down vote or attempt to close it because I think I can guess at it.

I assume you want to know why this occurs, it is simple security.

The "fix" is just as easy, hold down the power button and continue to hold for about 15-30 seconds and the device should hard reboot (essentially like pressing the RESET button on your computer).

You will need to perform the factory reset via recovery, so know the key combo and be ready to hold it immediately at restart, it might take a few tries to get the timing right.

Remember you will likely need the username and password of the Google account that resides on this device, or the reset will not matter and you will be locked in FRP.